# Resolving UWP Application Hangs

Tags: c#, uwp

I built a UWP application which logs data from an internal class to a .csv file using the CSVHelper library.  I am having a problem where the application stops responding when running in debug mode without any exceptions being thrown.  The app also does not crash.  In VS the diagnostic session timer is stopped but the code is still "running".  There is no stack trace when I break, the application won't hit any breakpoints and closing the app with the "X" closes the window visually but it doesn't end the debugging session and I suspect the process remains running.  I have to use the "Stop Debugging" button in visual studios to end the session.  It occurs at seemingly random intervals unrelated to what the app is currently doing.  The crashes are usually in the 50min+ execution time range though it has happened earlier.

How do I go about troubleshooting this issue?

I really don't know where to start without any exceptions or even a clue as to what causes the application to hit this state.  I would include code but other than just linking the entire repo I am not sure which sections would actually be helpful as I don't know, nor can I seem to find a way to identify what code is running to enter this state.

Comment: only in debug mode or also in release mode, how about just launching the app without VS.

Comment: @Leander I have only observed it in debug mode, I will try running in release and running the app without VS and report the results

Comment: Best way is from menu Debug : Break All.  Then get the call stack from menu Debug : Window : Call Stack.

Comment: @jdweng I have tried this but there is no call stack when I try this.

Comment: Then it stopped at main method at line current location (or in the loop where it stopped).  You can step (F11) to see what is executing.   You can also set break points and continue.  The code may running events and putting break points in the events will help determine what is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng When I break all after this occurs I can not resume code execution, I can't step through the code and breakpoints while they can be set are pointless because I can never resume execution.

Comment: @Leander I tried running overnight in release mode and the application did not crash, I hadn't tested the app in standalone yet though.

Comment: It sounds like events stopped working.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure what you mean, do you have any documentation or resources I should look at?

Comment: No.  is application hanging or just terminating?  Check task manager to see if process is running.

Comment: @jdweng The application just hangs, the process is still running in task manager.